# String to Number List Function Not Working

Tags: python, string, numbers

I am very new to Python programming and have been following a few video and website tutorials.  I am working on a few programming practice problems and am having trouble debugging.  Here is my first practice programming.  The function takes a string and converts it to a list of numbers. So 'a' becomes 0 and 'b' becomes 1, etc.  Its seemed really straight forward but I am getting the error 'IndexError: list index out of range'.  I've tried a few things, but I'm not sure what the problem is.  Can someone look at my code and see if I've made any obvious mistakes.  All help is greatly appreciated!

```
    import sys
    import string
    import math

    def string2nlist(m):
    characters =    ['a''b''c''d''e''f''g''h''i''j''k''l''m''n''o''p''q''r''s''t''u''v''w''x''y''z']
    numbers = ['0''1''2''3''4''5''6''7''8''9''10''11''12''13''14''15''16''17''18''19''20''21''22''23''24''25']
    newList = []
    msgLen = len(m)         # var msgLen will be an integer of the length

    print 'Message before conversion: ' + m

    index = 0               # iterate through message length in while loop
    while index < msgLen:
        letter = m[index]   # iterate through message m
        i = 0
        while i < 26:
            if letter == characters[i]:
                newList[index] = numbers[i]
            i = i + 1
        index = index + 1
    print newList
    return newList


    message = 'hello'
    newMessage = string2nlist(message)

    print 'Message after conversion: ', newMessage
```

Comment: Hello, welcome to Stackoverflow. Your lists are not valid. Values should be separated by commas!

Comment: @steko: They **are** valid, except they aren't doing what you think they're doing. Python implicitly collapses adjacent strings into a single string!

Comment: Thanks for that!! I am trying to learn very quickly and making stupid mistakes.  I've added the commas and now get 'IndexError: list assignment index out of range'  I will keep trying things.  Thanks again!

Comment: @jesiKat: You're assigning to an empty list - Python doesn't automatically create slots in the list as you assign, like some other languages. If you want to "append" to a list, there's a function for that: `mylist.append(someValue)`

Comment: I just found that too when I 'googled' my new error, Thanks very much!! I'm trying it now :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your lists seem to be formatted incorrectly. Try:

```
characters =    ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']
numbers = ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12','13','14','15','16','17','18','19','20','21','22','23','24','25']
```

Comment: No problem! If you don't mind, please mark the answer as correct (green checkmark).

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
characters = ['a''b''c''d''e''f''g''h''i''j''k''l''m''n''o''p''q''r''s''t''u''v''w''x''y''z']
numbers = ['0''1''2''3''4''5''6''7''8''9''10''11''12''13''14''15''16''17''18''19''20''21''22''23''24''25']
```

Python compiles adjacent string literals into a single string. This is useful in many cases, but unfortunately it means that it turned your lists into:

```
characters = ['abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz']
numbers = ['012345678910111213141516171819202122232425']
```

As was mentioned, add commas in between the characters.